# wp_nav_menu() with multiple Class

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I'm trying to make a menu with `wp_nav_menu()`. I'm trying to add multiple classes but I don't have experience with this. I think I have to overwrite a class but ...

```
<div class="top-menu">
<ul class="nav_menu">        
    <li class="nav_menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-p">PRODUCTS</a>
    <!-- ... -->
    </li>
    <li class="nav_menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-n">NEW</a>
        <ul class="nav_submenu">
        <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_menu-item">
    <!-- ... -->
    </li>
    <li class="nav_menu-item">
    <!-- ... -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could you help me with the code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your conditions are for each class by the hook you're looking for is [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class). You can use it to append classes or remove classes from each list-item `<li>` in the menu.

```
/**
 * Modify list item classes of wp_nav_menu
 * - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/
 *
 * @param Array $classes || List of list-item classes
 * @param WP_Nav_Item Object $item || The Nav Menu Object, NOT the WP_Post object
 *
 * @return Array $classes
 */
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {

    $menu_to_test_against = 'MENU NAME HERE';

    // Ensure we only apply this filter on the menu of our choice
    if( ! has_term( $menu_to_test_against, 'nav_menu', $item ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $classes[] = 'nav-p';
    $classes[] = 'nav-n';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```